# Excluding null fields in pojo response

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I want to exclude null fields from a pojo

****TransactionHistoryBO Pojo**

```html
package main.java.com.as.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionHistoryBO 
{
  private String processId;
  private String dateTime;
  private Integer status;
  private Double pointsEarned;
  private String productName;
  private String receiptNumber;
   
 public String getProcessId() {
  return processId;
 }
 public void setProcessId(String processId) {
  this.processId = processId;
 }


 public String getDateTime() {
  return dateTime;
 }
 public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
  this.dateTime = dateTime;
 }
 public Integer getStatus() {
  return status;
 }
 public void setStatus(Integer status) {
  this.status = status;
 }
 
 public Double getPointsEarned() {
  return pointsEarned;
 }

 public void setPointsEarned(Double pointsEarned) {
  this.pointsEarned = pointsEarned;
 }

 public String getProductName() {
  return productName;
 }
 
 public void setProductName(String productName) {
  this.productName = productName;
 }
 
 public String getReceiptNumber() {
  return receiptNumber;
 }
 public void setReceiptNumber(String receiptNumber) {
  this.receiptNumber = receiptNumber;
 }



}
```

**

**Transaction History Response pojo**

```html
public class TransactionHistoryResponse 
{
 private ArrayList<TransactionHistoryBO> transactions;
 
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 public ArrayList<TransactionHistoryBO> getTransactions() {
  return transactions;
 }
 @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
 public void setTransactions(ArrayList<TransactionHistoryBO> transactions) {
  this.transactions = transactions;
 }

 
 }
```

Array list of type Transaction History BO is used in Transaction History Response pojo.This is the exact pojo that i am showing in response.I would like to exclude the **fields with null values in Transaction History BO.**
I tried with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).It is not working..
Also tried with JsonSerialize,but it is deprecated.Jackson version used is 2.2.2.

Any help would be appreciated..please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionHistoryBO { ... }

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionHistoryResponse { ... }

public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        TransactionHistoryResponse thr = new TransactionHistoryResponse();
        TransactionHistoryBO thbo = new TransactionHistoryBO();
        thbo.setProductName("TEST");
        thr.setTransactions(new ArrayList<TransactionHistoryBO>());
        thr.getTransactions().add(thbo);
        System.out.print(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(thr));
    }

}
```

Produces output :

```
{
  "transactions" : [ {
    "productName" : "TEST"
  } ]
}
```

No other annotation is used. Just add @JsonInclude annotation to classes not properties.

---

**UPDATE:**

Add a custom JacksonJsonProvider to your application

```
@Provider
public class CustomJsonProvider extends ResteasyJackson2Provider {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = locateMapper(type, mediaType);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        super.writeTo(value, type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
    }

}
```

Register this provider in your web.xml

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name> 
    <param-value>com.package.CustomJsonProvider</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Tested with and without this and it works.

Comment: ,Thanks for your help.In my original post,i declared json include annotation at the the class level itself in TransactionHistoryBO. It's not working.Is there anyway where i can use the object mapper concept as you wrote ?FYI : I am using rest easy.It is automatically converting the pojo to json.

Comment: Did you add jsoninclude annotation to TransactionHistoryResponse class just like in my example ?

Comment: Updated my answer please check again.

Comment: i will try this and let you know..:)